# Laravel + Vue JS Routing shows page not found

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, vue.js, vue-router

I followed this tutorial https://laraveldaily.com/quick-start-laravel-5-5-vue-js-simple-crud-project/

However when I load : localhost/admin/companies  , I get page not found .

I tried to change to this too

```
const router = new VueRouter({
 routes: [
   { path: '/admin/companies', component: CompaniesController }
 ]
})
```

But I get "Syntax error { "  on the part VueRouter({ which I don't understand why. Can anyone help?

Thanks!

Comment: It is not laravel error. Looks like you made syntax mistake on your Vue code. Let me see your full code.

Comment: @Ts8060 Which section would you like to take a look? I will add on above. 
I changed my route to Route::get('/admin/companies', 'Api\V1\CompaniesController@index'); and it works. Not sure why the above using VueRouter not working.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Vue Router doesn't reload the page. Vue Router doesn't work like the Laravel Router. All it does whenever a Vue route changes, it mounts different component to a specific area. This area is defined by predefined **router-view** element.  It mounts the component according to the Vue route changes.

**Blade**

```
<div class='box'>
    <router-view name="content-viewport"></router-view>
</div>
```

**Vue**

```
const router = new VueRouter({
  routes: [
    { path: '/admin/companies', components: {"content-viewport" : CompaniesController} }
  ]
});
```

Now when you go to *domain#/admin/companies* Vue will mount the component CompaniesController in 'content-viewport'

Comment: Thank you ! Managed to solve this but you gave the solution I needed.

Answer (score 0):

In Vue js **<router-link** use to navigate the page from vue side.

In route, file route define here.

```
const router = new VueRouter({

  routes: [
    { path: '/admin/companies', redirect: { name: 'CompaniesController' } },
  ],
})


<router-link to="/about">Go</router-link>
```

Then call localhost/admin/companies then the page will load.